# Equivalent to NPM or Gems for Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

Is the an equivalent for play of NPM modules and gems for the play framework? My searching yields nothing.

Comment: You mean some place to find dependencies or a way to add them to your project? If you just want to add dependencies, see [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html).

Comment: @marcospereira A repo for 3rd party libraries is what I was after

Comment: Are you looking for a library in particular or you want to browse a directory and discover new ones ? See https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Maven repository and use SBT for use them.